# How to dynamically create a shortcut to a folder in openedge progress

Tags: winapi, shortcut, progress-4gl, openedge

Is it possible to create a shortcut from withing the app-builder?
Perhaps a Win32 API function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly, what do you need. When it is creating of new shortcut from ABL-program, then you can use the statement OS-COMMAND and call a MKLINK.

```
OS-COMMAND SILENT VALUE("MKLINK C:\temp\330_Neu_link.xml C:\temp\330_Neu.xml").
```